# Placement of showkeys label

Tags: etoolbox, showkeys

Is it possible to place the labels of the showkeys package for bibliographic items on the right side instead of the default left?

I tried

```
\patchcmd{\SK@@label}{\llap}{\rlap}{}{}
```

which indeed changes the location of the label but not very satisfying.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{test} test
\item \label{test2} test2
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean in the right margin?

Comment: ...and this is *specific* to showing `\bibitem`s or `\item`s from _any_ list?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the package [showlabels](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showlabels) that solved similar issue for me. It has a number of options to display labels at various sides of the page or in the text.

Comment: showlabels is great but only prints labels, not \ref, \cite nor bib.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a little more to shove entries over to the right of your document. Another patch pushes it over by `\textwidth+\marginparsep`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showkeys,etoolbox,showframe}
\newcommand{\fullrlap}[1]{%
  \rlap{\kern\dimexpr-\@totalleftmargin+\textwidth+\marginparsep\relax#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{x}
  \bibitem{abc} test1
  \bibitem{def} test2
\end{thebibliography}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\SK@@label}{\llap}{\fullrlap}{}{}% Insert appropriate (full)rlap patch
\makeatother

\begin{thebibliography}{x}
  \bibitem{ghi} test3
  \bibitem{jkl} test4
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

The negative `\@totalleftmargin` moves the label flush with the left margin. To that, we add `\textwidth` in order to shove the label over to the right margin and then another `\marginparsep`.

Comment: The lower "References" becomes such that "totalleftmargin+[ghi]" prints in the same place with "[1] test 3" (messing the two with each other). Similarly for the second line. It becomes decent with "\rlap{\kern\dimexpr+\textwidth\relax#1}}". However, if I place the trick inside \ifshowkeys{...}, which reads \newcommand{\ifshowkeys}[1]{#1}, I get the error "Argument of \llap has an extra }. }" 
Even without that, I get theorem and equation labels to the right but section labels etc.  to the left, likely because of hyperref.