# Put all labels on the left with showkeys

Tags: labels, showkeys, showlabels

My document has a very narrow right margin and I'm using showkeys to see internal labels for equations. Is it possible to put all labels that showkeys generates on the left side?

Unfortunatelly, there is no option in the package that directly allows this, but maybe it's possible to patch or redefine corresponding commands somehow? There is a related question ([Placement of showkeys label](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/190918/placement-of-showkeys-label)) but I'm not into extended stuff like that to make a good use of that example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come across similar package [showlabels](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showlabels) that solved the issue. It has a number of options to show specified labels on the left or right margins of the page as well as in an inline mode.